# Joining filesystem paths in C

Tags: c, filesystems, path-separator

Similar to how python has the convenient `os.path.join()` function, I was wondering if there was a good cross-platform way to do this in C.

My current approach is to set up some preprocessor directives with something like this

```
#ifdef defined(linux)
#define PATH_SEPARATOR "/"
#else
#define PATH_SEPARATOR "\\"
#endif
```

Comment: fwiw, I'm pretty sure all modern Windows OS support "/" path separators.

Comment: Hm, you could simply use `/` for everything, this should work for Windows and POSIX (although it might not on some other operating systems, so it depends on *how* portable your code has to be).

Comment: Cross platform? C? Bah hahaha XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure many cross-platform libraries have such functionality. Maybe you want to have a look at APR's [apr_filepath_merge](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/trunk/group__apr__filepath.html#gae89fd67108f10dc5044b6d062dde0138) function.

In C++, you could use Boost:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

[...]    

path path1("/tmp");
path path2("example");
path result = path1 / path2;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard way to do this. Do it yourself or use a library. For example the Apache Portable Runtime provides [apr_filepath_merge](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__filepath.html#gae89fd67108f10dc5044b6d062dde0138).

Answer (score 1):

For C, you could use [cwalk](https://likle.github.io/cwalk/) which is a little cross-platform library to do file path related things (either [cwk_path_join](https://likle.github.io/cwalk/reference/cwk_path_join.html) or [cwk_path_join_multiple](https://likle.github.io/cwalk/reference/cwk_path_join_multiple.html)):

```
#include <cwalk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buffer[FILENAME_MAX];

  cwk_path_join("hello/there", "../world", buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  printf("The combined path is: %s", buffer);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Outputs:

```
The combined path is: hello/world
```